# Python loop control

Tags: python

What is equivalent to

```
for (I=2; I<n; I*=2)
```

in python.
I tried to do this with range() function and I know how it works with increment only. But here I want to multiply it in each iteration. I don't want to do it manually in side the loop

Comment: This is an infinite loop. `0 * 2` is `0`.

Comment: Show your code,the error your getting and what result your expecting.That will help us on helping you.

Comment: this is syntax for java or c++ i want to do it in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `while` is easy, `while` is also slow. Try:

```
In [3]: import math

In [4]: n = 10

In [5]: for i in (2**n for n in range(1, int(math.log2(n)) + 1)):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:
2
4
8

In [6]: n = 40

In [7]: for i in (2**n for n in range(1, int(math.log2(n)) + 1)):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:
2
4
8
16
32

In [8]: n = 60

In [9]: for i in (2**n for n in range(1, int(math.log2(n)) + 1)):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:
2
4
8
16
32

In [10]: n = 100

In [11]: for i in (2**n for n in range(1, int(math.log2(n)) + 1)):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

Comment: please consider, that 1/2 = 0 in python2, so 0.5 can be more general; plus n**(0.5) is not what you need here. You should use log2.

Comment: @quantummind again, you are absolutely correct. I've edited it one more time. It's been one of those mornings...

Comment: >>> import this  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple is the rule in python.  While is easy:

```
n = 20
i = 2

while (i<n):
    print "the i variable is "+str(i)
    i = i * 2
```

I (originally, this has since been changed) used addition for this simple example, multiplication would simply use the "*" operator as you did.

Comment: The question says I*=2, which is multiplication, i = i + 2 in your answer is addition.

Comment: The comment notes that.  Concept is being taught; I write real code for money.

Comment: OK, I would like to revoke down-vote, but I cannot do that until you edit your answer. Consider that you might do what the customer asked, instead of writing what you want, and tell him that he can modify it to work as he/she wanted. :-)